# Image Resize in drupal

Tags: drupal-7, image-resizing

I have to resize and save an uploaded image to 60X60px. I tried using image_resize in drupal & I am passing the correct arguments as :

1. $image = my image object
2. $width = 60
3. $height = 60
   While debugging when it enters in image_toolkit_invoke, it requires $image->toolkit at one place which I cannot find in my $image object. This in turn returns FALSE and my image is not being resized.

```html
function image_resize(stdClass $image, $width, $height) {
  $width = (int) round($width);
  $height = (int) round($height);

  return image_toolkit_invoke('resize', $image, array($width, $height));
}
```

May I know that how can I get toolkit in my image object or is there any other way for resizing the image?
Also I tried using

```html
<img src = "pathtoimagefile" width="60" height="60">
```

at the place where my html will be render after the image is uploaded. But this is not working. Is something here?

Comment: Not an answer, but resizing to a specific width+height will most probably break aspect ratio unless all your source images are also squares... better resize only 1 dimension and use CSS to hide the overflowing content and display a square.

Comment: @Bartdude concern for the aspect ratio is not required here for me. Can you please tell me any other method? Because my site is anyways displaying a square image that is of some other width and height.  I just want to change that here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Image styles. let you set standard graphic templates so that the images on your website have a consistent size, scale, and rotation.

View this link https://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/working-image-styles

Good luck